# In IE - Access Denied when changing location.hash of iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-8

I have 2 windows such as Parent window and child window ( child is iframe ), for the parent window I have changed the default domain from x.localdomain.com to localdomain.com and for the child I have set the same domain (localdomain.com ) which is a dynamic iframe. When I change the location hash in the iframe, I get an access denied error.

This happens only in IE 8.

Comment: Please show some code causing this error. Is the error triggered by parent window or child, or maybe both?

Comment: What is the value of `document.domain` at the time you try to set `location.hash`?